# Spyder error : "It seems the kernel died unexpectedly. Use 'Restart kernel' to continue using this console."

Tags: python, ipython, spyder

So it started a couple days ago, I think I recieved this after some heavy code. But I'm not too sure. It happens just when I **start up spyder** and this message keeps printing in the **ipython console**

> It seems the kernel died unexpectedly. Use 'Restart kernel' to
>   continue using this console.

I've tried reset Spyder to default settings and installing new version of Anaconda, but no luck. I'm running python 2.7 on Windows 7 (64 bit) with Spyder 2.3.8.

After a while I receive this message in the internal console:

```
WARNING:root:kernel died: 3.00999999046
Exception in thread Thread-8:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Will\Anaconda2\lib\threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Will\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\channels.py", line 162, in run
    self._create_socket()
  File "C:\Users\Will\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\channels.py", line 89, in _create_socket
    self.socket = self.context.socket(zmq.REQ)
  File "C:\Users\Will\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\zmq\sugar\context.py", line 138, in socket
    s = self._socket_class(self, socket_type)
  File "zmq/backend/cython/socket.pyx", line 279, in zmq.backend.cython.socket.Socket.__cinit__ (zmq\backend\cython\socket.c:3384)
ZMQError: Too many open files
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Comment: I installed Ubuntu on the side of Windows and installed Python on it. Not exactly a fix, but I can at least use Spyder now.